# Where does the Java Preferences API store the data on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, preferences

I'm trying to find where the [Preferences API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/) stores saved data on Linux. Does anyone know?

Comment: Ahh excellent. I looked in ~/.java but didn't see the hidden folder.

Comment: default value seems to be ~/.java/.userPrefs for user prefs and for system prefs its /etc/.java/.systemPrefs if exists else $JAVA_HOME/.systemPrefs